# data.table: group-by, sum, name new column, and slice columns in one step

Tags: r, group-by, data.table, rename

This seems like it should be easy, but I've never been able to figure out how to do it. Using `data.table` I want to sum a column, `C`, by another column `A`, and just keep those two columns. At the same time, I want to be able to name the new column. My attempts and desired output:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(A= c('a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'), B=c('19', '20', '21', '22', '23'),
C=c(150,250,20,220,130))

# Desired Output - is there a way to do this in one step using data.table? #
new.data <- dt[, sum(C), by=A]
setnames(new.data,'V1', 'C.total')
new.data
   A C.total
1: a     150
2: b     270
3: c     350

# Attempt 1: Problem is that columns B and C kept, extra rows kept #
new.data <- dt[, 'C.total' := sum(C), by=A]
new.data
   A  B   C C.total
1: a 19 150     150
2: b 20 250     270
3: b 21  20     270
4: c 22 220     350
5: c 23 130     350

# Attempt 2: Problem is that new column not named #
new.data <- dt[, sum(C), by=A]
new.data
   A  V1
1: a 150
2: b 270
3: c 350
```

Comment: Have you gone through the [Getting started](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) vignettes yet?

Comment: I did look at the vignettes for the answer first (they are very helpful and a good way to learn about data.table). I did not see this answer, though, but now that I know what to look for I see that a similar answer is under "Inside each group, why are the group variables length 1?" and and "Unused arguments" error, neither of which are obvious that they are solutions to this question. Did you have a particular section you were thinking of?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken about what you want to do, section 1d explains how to name columns..

Comment: @Arun: as a four-year user of data.table, I've been through the vignettes, doc, MDowle's FAQ, three different cheatsheets, several slide presentations, YouTube tutorials, all of SO a hundred times over etc. This syntax is hidden! It's very unintuitive that `df[, V2 = sum(C), by=A]` gives a cryptic syntax 'Error: unused argument' yet adding `list()` or `.()` makes it legit. Needs to be described way more prominently!

Comment: @smci I have a newer data.table cheat sheet that lets you search for tasks by category, so you could filter the table by topic like "summarize" and then see all the possibilities, including "Run summary calculations on data by one group and name new column." The HTML version of the table is here https://www.infoworld.com/article/3575086/the-ultimate-r-datatable-cheat-sheet.html or you can download the HTML file (free registration req'd) at https://www.infoworld.com/article/3586153/download-infoworlds-ultimate-r-datatable-cheat-sheet.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `list` (or `.`):

```
> dt[, list(C.total = sum(C)), by=A]
   A C.total
1: a     150
2: b     270
3: c     350
```

Comment: where in the documentation is this described?