# R data.table dynamic column name of group by returning new table

Tags: r, data.table

By default a group by operation on a data.table returns a new data.table with an automatically named column `V1`:

```
dt <- data.table(a = sample(1:100, 100), b = sample(1:100, 100), id = rep(1:10,10))
dt[, mean(a), by = id]

#     id V1
# 1:  1 48.2
# 2:  2 47.9
# 3:  3 46.8
# 4:  4 54.7
# 5:  5 63.7
# 6:  6 50.6
# 7:  7 43.3
# 8:  8 52.7
# 9:  9 45.4
# 10: 10 51.7
```

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32124630/data-table-group-by-sum-name-new-column-and-slice-columns-in-one-step) I can set the name of the column with the results like so

```
dt[, list(mean = mean(a)), by = id]
```

Is it possible to have a variable for the column name? E.g., instead of setting `mean` explicitly I would like to do something like

```
column_name <- "mean"
dt[, list(column_name = mean(a)), by = id]  # resulting column name is column_name (and not mean)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `setNames`

```
library(data.table)
dt[, setNames(list(mean(a)), column_name), by = id]

#    id mean
# 1:  1 56.8
# 2:  2 50.5
# 3:  3 50.5
# 4:  4 42.4
# 5:  5 49.9
# 6:  6 47.8
# 7:  7 60.6
# 8:  8 57.4
# 9:  9 54.6
#10: 10 34.5
```

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.table(a = sample(1:100, 100), b = sample(1:100, 100), id = rep(1:10,10))
column_name <- "mean"
```

Comment: With verbose=TRUE, you'll see that this disables GForce. If https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1803 is handled, it could be done like `dt[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=id, .SDcols=setNames("a", column_name)]` maybe.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `setnames` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setnames(dt[, .(mean(a)), by = id], 'V1', column_name)[]
#    id mean
# 1:  1 56.8
# 2:  2 50.5
# 3:  3 50.5
# 4:  4 42.4
# 5:  5 49.9
# 6:  6 47.8
# 7:  7 60.6
# 8:  8 57.4
# 9:  9 54.6
#10: 10 34.5
```

#### data

```
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.table(a = sample(1:100, 100), b = sample(1:100, 100), id = rep(1:10,10))
column_name <- "mean"
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, you could also deploy a loop that returns a named list. For example, using `Map()`:

```r
dt[
  , Map(
    function(i) {
      mean(a)
    }
    , i = "Mean"
  )
  , by = id
]
```

Or for 2+ function calls/columns:

```r
dt[
  , Map(
    function(i, fun) {
      do.call(
        fun
        , list(a)
      )
    }
    , i = c("Mean", "SD")
    , fun = c(mean, sd)
  )
  , by = id
]
#     id Mean       SD
#  1:  1 56.8 29.23012
#  2:  2 50.5 26.18842
#  3:  3 50.5 24.82047
#  4:  4 42.4 34.72495
#  5:  5 49.9 26.99979
#  6:  6 47.8 28.35411
#  7:  7 60.6 31.52142
#  8:  8 57.4 32.22904
#  9:  9 54.6 27.90141
# 10: 10 34.5 30.94529
```